# Отображение результата после нажатия кнопки

Tags: события, javascript

Помогите, пожалуйста, переделать так, чтобы input не был "живым" (то есть не показывал количество слов СРАЗУ, а только после нажатия кнопки). http://pastebin.com/BR2CUJT2

```
<html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="m" cols="48" rows="5" onKeyDown="textCounter(this)" onKeyUp="textCounter(this)"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="counter" value="0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function textCounter(el) {
            document.getElementById("counter").value = el.value.split(" ").length
        }
    </script>
    <br>
    <button onclick="calc()">Поиск</button>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: На input вешаем событие "ввод" (keydown вроде) и вызываем метод объекта события preventDefault. Это отменит стандартное поведение input-а, а дальше делайте с ним что хотите.

Answer (score 1):

```
 <html> 
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <textarea name="m" id="m" cols="48" rows="5"></textarea>
    <input type="text" id="counter" value="0">
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function calc() {
            var m = document.getElementById("m");
            document.getElementById("counter").value = m.value.split(" ").length;
        }
    </script>
    <br>
    <button onclick="calc()">Поиск</button>
</body>
</html>
```